# Textfield displaying data in multiple line even when the multiline property is set to false

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6, htmltext

I am displaying dynamic data in the text field and its multiline property is set to false, but for one the data row the data is displayed in 2 lines instead of one. I tried to set the data to the htmlText as well as normal text but still the issue remains.

I also tried to remove the HTML tags but still the issue is there.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `wordWrap`?

Comment: And what is an example of the text being put into the textfield?

Comment: my_text.wordWrap = false;

Comment: The content is been read from a RSS feed, it contains HTML tags, i have tried removing the html tags as well but the issue still remains.

Comment: The only structural difference is that for all the data that is displayed properly the description is direct child of a <div>, for e.g <div>content</div>, for the row which is not displayed properly has the following structure <div><div>content</div></div>, but what difference should that make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what the issue was, the issue was in the data that was received from RSS feed, it  had line break + many white spaces, so i replaced the line break and white spaces and now the issue is resolved. Thanks